# What better way to Simulate this Popcorn in the Bucket?

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to simulate a lot of popcorn in a bucket, what's the best way to simulate them in the bucket? I know the method of Rigidy Body Simulation, creating several popcorn, is there a better way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you need full bucket or just popcorn at the top of it? Do you plan to simulate it later on (knock it over)?

Comment: It will become an asset to a game, I need it just at the top! :)
But I wanted to simulate her downfall, to make the organization more organic.